# Write audio stream to an ALSA device with ffmpeg

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, alsa, ffmpeg

I used `snd-aloop` module to create  a loopback audio stream. Now I want to somehow mux my desktop audio from pulseaudio and my microphone audio streams into this loopback stream, and while that can be done via ffmpeg, I can't find a way to write the output to the ALSA device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this, all I had to do was to specify the format of the output "file" as `alsa` and set output to `hw:[snd-aloop-card],1,0`

Example: `ffmpeg -i myfile.ogg -f alsa hw:2,1,0`

Comment: That's brilliant! It also worked for me when I specified `-f alsa default` as output, so I don't have to think which one it is. It's probably pipewire underneath which sends it to whatever I picked in my desktop settings.